# Parse Data Encryption ... Where to Put the Key

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Need to encrypt few attributes in a Parse class, as part of a design requirement. Encryption and decryption  are easy enough; however, I am not sure as how to go about "hiding" the cipher key. At the moment, putting the key in an object, with restricted ACL, seems to be the only option. However, if Parse account is compromised, so are the user data. Ideally, would like to set the key as a persistent volatile variable within main.js. Is this possible? Alternatively, what are the best set of practices?
Cheers,

Comment: You can always use Cloud Code

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I am using cloud-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IQrypt Vault](http://iqrypt.com/docs/Vault/) to store the encryption key. With IQryptParse you can also encrypt/decrypt fields values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.